# Need help converting (CFPropertyListRef *)nsdictionary to swift

Tags: swift, objective-c, macos, coremidi

I need a little help converting this

```
 MIDIDeviceRef midiDevice = MIDIGetDevice(i);
NSDictionary *midiProperties;

MIDIObjectGetProperties(midiDevice, (CFPropertyListRef *)&midiProperties, YES);
NSLog(@"Midi properties: %d \n %@", i, midiProperties);
```

to swift. I have this but I am getting hung up on casting the CFPropertList.

```
 var midiDevice = MIDIGetDevice(index)
let midiProperties =  NSDictionary()

 MIDIObjectGetProperties(midiDevice,  CFPropertyListRef(midiProperties), 1);
println("Midi properties: \(index) \n \(midiProperties)");
```

Any help would be great.

Thanks

Comment: You're using constructed object in constant. You need a pointer to NSDictionary, so MIDIObjectGetProperties could create object and overwrite it thus returning a value.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is the signature for `MIDIObjectGetProperties` in Swift:

```
func MIDIObjectGetProperties(obj: MIDIObjectRef, outProperties: UnsafeMutablePointer<Unmanaged<CFPropertyList>?>, deep: Boolean) -> OSStatus
```

So you need to pass in an `UnsafeMutablePointer` to a `Unmanaged<CFPropertyList>?`:

```
var midiDevice = MIDIGetDevice(0)
var unmanagedProperties: Unmanaged<CFPropertyList>?

MIDIObjectGetProperties(midiDevice, &unmanagedProperties, 1)
```

Now you have your properties, but they're in an unmanaged variable -- you can use the `takeUnretainedValue()` method to get them out, and then cast the resulting `CFPropertyList` to an `NSDictionary`:

```
if let midiProperties: CFPropertyList = unmanagedProperties?.takeUnretainedValue() {
    let midiDictionary = midiProperties as NSDictionary
    println("Midi properties: \(index) \n \(midiDictionary)");
} else {
    println("Couldn't load properties for \(index)")
}
```

Results:

```
Midi properties: 0 
 {
    "apple.midirtp.errors" = <>;
    driver = "com.apple.AppleMIDIRTPDriver";
    entities =     (
    );
    image = "/Library/Audio/MIDI Drivers/AppleMIDIRTPDriver.plugin/Contents/Resources/RTPDriverIcon.tiff";
    manufacturer = "";
    model = "";
    name = Network;
    offline = 0;
    scheduleAheadMuSec = 50000;
    uniqueID = 442847711;
}
```